# Jquery isn't generating/adding content as it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created a function that checks the select field and generates html accordingly. The problem is it doesn't seem to be working, and I'm pretty stuck. One thing I immediately notice is that the select fields don't gain the classes they should, that is the 'smart'/'flex', please check it out, any and all help is much appreciated.

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lkynofvr/)

JQUERY

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  // Calculates interest for smart loan
  function smart_interest($desired_interest) {
    return (($desired_interest * 13) + 0.997) / 13;
  }

  // Calculates periodic payment for smart loan
  function pmt_value($interest_rate, $pay_period, $present_value) {
    return Math.round($present_value * ($interest_rate / (1 - Math.pow((1 + $interest_rate), -$pay_period))));
  }

  // div within popup to apply data
  var info_div = $('div.jcontent'),
    // dropdowns
    selected_option = $('.loanCalc select.loan-type option:selected'),
    selected_amount = $('.loanCalc select.loan option:selected'),
    selected_plan = $('.loanCalc select.loan-type'),
    months = [6,12,18,24];

  function calc_rates() {
    if (selected_plan.hasClass('smart')) {
      // user's present value - loan amount
      var pv = selected_amount.val(),
          payments = {};
      // if - check pv range 
      if (pv < 999) {
        // interest
        var interest = 0.10,
        // smart interest
        smart_interest = smart_interest(interest);
        // each payment
        for(var i = 0, len = months.length; i < len; i++) {
          var payment = pmt_value(smart_interest, months[i], pv);
              payments[i] = payment;
          // return object loaded with payments
              return payments;
        }
      }
      else if (1000 <= pv < 4999) {
        // interest
        var interest = 0.09,
        // smart interest
        smart_interest = smart_interest(interest);
        // each payment
        for(var i = 0, len = months.length; i < len; i++) {
          var payment = pmt_value(smart_interest, months[i], pv);
              payments[i] = payment;
          // return object loaded with payments
              return payments;
        }
      }
      else if (5000 <= pv <= 10000) {
        // interest
        var interest = 0.08,
        // smart interest
        smart_interest = smart_interest(interest);
        // each payment
        for(var i = 0, len = months.length; i < len; i++) {
          var payment = pmt_value(smart_interest, months[i], pv);
              payments[i] = payment;
          // return object loaded with payments
              return payments;
        }
      }
    } else if (selected_plan.hasClass('flex')) {
      // user's present value - loan amount
      var pv = selected_amount.val(); 
      if (pv < 999) {
        // interest
        var interest = 0.15;
        // return interest of price 
        return pv * interest;
      }
      else if (1000 <= pv < 4999) {
        var interest = 0.125;
        // return interest of price 
        return pv * interest;
      }
      else if (5000 <= pv <= 10000) {
        var interest = 0.950;
        // return interest of price 
        return pv * interest;
      }
    }
  }

  // Upon Change of the dropdown fields - check both arent default
  $('div.loanCalc .loan-type','div.loanCalc .loan').change(function(){
    if(selected_option.val() == "5") {
    selected_plan.removeClass('smart');
    selected_plan.addClass('flex');
  }
  else if(selected_option.val() == "2") {
    selected_plan.removeClass('flex');
    selected_plan.addClass('smart');
  }
    if($('div.loanCalc .loan-type').val() !== 0 && $('div.loanCalc .loan').val() !== 0) {
      // for smart plan
      if (selected_plan.hasClass('smart')) {
        var payments = calc_rates(),
        html = "<ul><li>$" + payments[0] + " 6 month plan</li><li>$" + payments[1] + " 12 month plan</li><li>$" + payments[2] + " 18 month plan</li><li>$" + payments[3] + " 24 month plan</li></ul>";
        // Container for content
        info_div.append(html);
    }
      else if (selected_plan.hasClass('flex')) {
        var payment = calc_rates(),
        html = "<p class = 'flex-cost'>$" + payment + "</p>";
        info_div.append(html);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="loanCalc">
  <div class="loanPlan">
    <select name="loanType" class="loan-type empty">
      <option value="0" disabled="" selected="">Loan Type Desired</option>
      <option value="5" class = "flex">30 Day Flexible Loan</option>
      <option value="2" class = "smart">Smart Pay Installment Loan</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="loanAmount">
    <select name="loanAmount" class="loan empty">
      <option value="0" disabled="" selected="">Loan Amount Desired</option>
      <option value="750">$750</option>
      <option value="800">$800</option>
      <option value="850">$850</option>
      <option value="900">$900</option>
      <option value="950">$950</option>
      <option value="1000">$1000</option>
      <option value="1250">$1250</option>
      <option value="1500">$1500</option>
      <option value="1750">$1750</option>
      <option value="2000">$2000</option>
      <option value="2250">$2250</option>
      <option value="2500">$2500</option>
      <option value="2750">$2750</option>
      <option value="3000">$3000</option>
      <option value="3250">$3250</option>
      <option value="3500">$3500</option>
      <option value="3750">$3750</option>
      <option value="4000">$4000</option>
      <option value="4250">$4250</option>
      <option value="4500">$4500</option>
      <option value="5000">$5000</option>
      <option value="5500">$5500</option>
      <option value="6000">$6000</option>
      <option value="6500">$6500</option>
      <option value="7000">$7000</option>
      <option value="7500">$7500</option>
      <option value="8000">$8000</option>
      <option value="8500">$8500</option>
      <option value="9000">$9000</option>
      <option value="9500">$9500</option>
      <option value="10000">$10000</option>
    </select>
    <p class="info-one">Monthly Payment</p>
    <div class="jcontent"></div>
    <p class="info-two"><span class="span">Monthly payment includes principal   
    and interest. Your loan balance is  
    zero at the end of the plan</span>
    <span class="flex">Monthly Payment is interest only and 
    does not pay down the loan balance</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're setting all the `selected_XXX` variables when the page loads, not after the user selects something from the drop-down.

Comment: in your jsfiddle, you have an option called jshint. click this, and then scroll through your js. you'll find a lot of red dots at the beginning of a js line - get rid of the js errors and if it's still not working, come back to us ;)

Comment: @errand Those are all just style warnings about duplicate `var` statements.

Comment: @barmar you are right. was just my first shot, before digging deeper into the issue ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `$('select.loan-type' , 'select.loan').change(function(){`

to

`$('select.loan-type , select.loan').change(function(){`

or else selector won't fire event.

you also need to initilize the values for variables after change:

```
$('select.loan-type , select.loan').change(function(){
    selected_option = $('.loanCalc select.loan-type option:selected'),
    selected_amount = $('.loanCalc select.loan option:selected'),
    selected_plan = $('.loanCalc select.loan-type'),
    months = [6,12,18,24];
    if(selected_option.val() == "5") {
    selected_plan.removeClass('smart');
    selected_plan.addClass('flex');
  }
```

i'm also not sure what you are trying to achive here:

`var interest = 0.10,`

this gives an error. you probably need to change `var interest = 0.10,` to `var interest = 0.10;` and also in other places where you put `,` instead of `;`

also in this for loop you return a value right after the first iteration:

```
for(var i = 0, len = months.length; i < len; i++) {
          var payment = pmt_value(smart_interest, months[i], pv);
              payments[i] = payment;
          // return object loaded with payments
              return payments;
        }
```

this and any other places it has the same loop should be changed to:

```
for(var i = 0, len = months.length; i < len; i++) {
          var payment = pmt_value(smart_interest, months[i], pv);
              payments[i] = payment;
        }
// return object loaded with payments
              return payments;
```

and any `smart_interest = smart_interest(interest);` should be changed to `s_interest = smart_interest(interest);` you cannot call a variable name in the name of a function, it's generally bad coding.

i'm also not sure if this is what you want but in order to change the content of your `info_div` and not append to it each change, you need to replace `info_div.append(html);` with `info_div.html(html);` (once again replace here variable named `html` with some other name, even that it's working that why).

see this fully working 
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lkynofvr/9/)

Comment: thank you so much, I've just learned a lot, really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2):

```
 selected_option = $('.loanCalc select.loan-type option:selected'),
```

This line is part of the issue. The selected_option holds the option item which is selected at the beginning. If the select box is changed, selected_option still holds the option with the value "0".

I suggest the following. Change the HTML with an ID

```
  <select name="loanType" class="loan-type empty" id="loan_type">
      <option value="0" disabled="" selected="">Loan Type Desired</option>
      <option value="5" class = "flex">30 Day Flexible Loan</option>
      <option value="2" class = "smart">Smart Pay Installment Loan</option>
    </select>
```

Then query the id:

```
   var loanType = $("#loan_type");
     ...
     if (loanType.val() == "2") {
         //do stuff
     } else if (loanType.val() == "5") {
         //do other stuff
     }
```

Additionally the answer from Edan Feiles has to be followed.

> change $('select.loan-type' , 'select.loan').change(function(){
>
> to
>
> $('select.loan-type , select.loan').change(function(){